# Добавить звездочку * в обязательных полях формы form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Необходимо в Rails 4 на основе правил валидации модели добавлять к обязательным полям звездочку *

Форма (haml):

```
= form_for @promo_code do |f|
  = f.error_messages
  = field_set_tag  t('promo_codes.details') do
    .splitContainer
      %dl.half
        %dt= f.label :code, t('promo_codes.code')
        %dd= f.text_field :code, :class => 'text focus'
  ...
```

Валидация в модели PromoCode

```
validates :code, :presence => true
```

Answer (score 1):

Расширяем хелпер FormBuilder

создаем файл в **config/initializers/form_builder.rb**

```
class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  alias :orig_label :label

  def label(method, content_or_options = nil, options = nil, &block)
    if content_or_options && content_or_options.class == Hash
      options = content_or_options
    else
      content = content_or_options
    end

    if object.class.respond_to?(:validators_on) &&
        object.class.validators_on(method).map(&:class).include?(ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator)

      if options.class != Hash
        options = {:class => "required"}
      else
        options[:class] = ((options[:class] || "") + " required").split(" ").uniq.join(" ")
      end
    end

    self.orig_label(method, content, options || {}, &block)
  end
end
```

CSS стиль:

```
label.required:after {
  content: " *";
  color: #FF7676;
}
```

Перезапускаем приложение. На этом все.